# Calculating start and end selection indices in HTML through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the start and end selection indices in browsers other than IE in contentEditable 'div'. For Ex., IE has the following method.

```
var oSelection;
var oTxtRange;
var units = -100000;
var iStartIndex = -1, iEndIndex = -1;

if(document.selection)      // IE..
{
  oSelection = document.selection;
  oTxtRange = oSelection.createRange();

  if(oTxtRange)
  {
    iStartIndex = oTxtRange.moveStart('character',units);
    iEndIndex = oTxtRange.moveEnd('character',units);
    iStartIndex *= -1;
    iEndIndex *= -1;
  }
}
```

I understand that above method is not a W3C standard. I have gone through W3C documentation for Selection and Range object, but still couldn't help finding solution for Chrome and FireFox. Solution in JQuery is also welcome.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: Take a look here, maybe it will help: http://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: Why do you need this? What use are the numbers you get out of this?

Comment: fabrik: that's not related to the question being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following in non-IE browsers. It returns offsets of the selection boundaries within the visible body text of the page like the IE version does, but I'm not sure what use these numbers will be.

```
function getBodyTextOffset(node, offset) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.body);
    range.setEnd(node, offset);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    return sel.toString().length;
}

function getSelectionOffsets() {
    var sel, range;
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(sel.rangeCount - 1);
            start = getBodyTextOffset(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            end = getBodyTextOffset(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
            alert(start + ", " + end);
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        // IE stuff here
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, your solution works. Great. And about the scenario where I am using it is like this. Suppose, you make <body> as contentEditable, and you want to allow user to typing at particular position say in-between <span id='allowTyping'>Hello</span> element. At that time, to make sure that selection is within that element while typing. Thank you very much. :-)